# is there an opposite to curl or wget to upload a directry to a webdav server

Tags: curl, wget, webdav

Hi I know `curl` and `wget` for Windows. But I would need an opposite program for windows to upload a directory tree to a webdav server. I do know `carotdav` etc. but I would it need as `command line` onliner to include it into a Windows Batch file. Do anyone here know of such a tool? Thanks

Comment: Hi ! You can upload, even with `curl` :) Please have a look [here](https://superuser.com/a/941561) for an example.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/stokito/cf82ce965718ce87f36b78f7501d7940 more curl examples

Comment: Also there's [cadaver](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/cadaver.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

[rclone](https://rclone.org/) allows to do that.

See other options https://github.com/stokito/awesome-webdav#cli